# Return NULL values only if all the values are NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this situation where I want the most recent Begin Date only if it doesn't have an End Date (i.e. the End Date is NULL).
This is an example of what I have below

| ID | Begin Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID12 | 9-2-2022 | 12-4-2022 |
| ID12 | 8-1-2022 | 10-2-2022 |
| ID12 | 7-1-2022 | NULL |
| ID12 | 6-1-2022 | NULL |
| ID13 | 4-1-2022 | NULL |
| ID13 | 5-1-2022 | NULL |
| ID14 | 2-1-2022 | NULL |
| ID14 | 3-1-2022 | NULL |
| ID14 | 1-1-2022 | 2-1-2022 |

Expected result: I want something like this if the most recent Begin Date doesn't have an End Date in it for the same ID.

| ID | Begin Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID13 | 5-1-2022 | NULL |
| ID14 | 3-1-2022 | NULL |

So ID12 will be excluded from the report because it has an End Date for the most recent Begin Date which is 9-2-2022. I want distinct value for each ID.

```
SELECT ID, MAX (Begin Date), End Date
FROM TableA
WHERE End Date IS NULL 
ORDER BY Begin Date DESC
```

Comment: What is that second table in the question with two rows in it? Is this the desired results? If so where does "most recent Begin Date" come into it?

Comment: @MartinSmith yes this is the desired result. I just want the most recent begin date (eg 5-1-2022, in this case)  if the end date for that particular ID has all null values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having` clauses and `count()` to determine the IDs with null values only

```
select *
from mytable
where ID in (
  select ID
  from mytable
  group by ID
  having count([End Date]) = 0
);
```

---

After updating your requirements :

First determine the most recent `Begin DATE` for each `ID` then apply an inner join to get the expected result

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join (
  select ID, MAX([Begin Date]) as [MAX Begin DATE]
  from mytable
  group by ID
) as s on s.ID = t.ID and s.[MAX Begin DATE] = t.[Begin DATE]
where t.[End DATE] is null
```

Comment: I made an edit to the original question, your code actually works to my original but I realized some other changes that need to be made.

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate and use `COUNT` to count non-null values. If it returns 0 then all are null.

```
SELECT
  ID,
  [Begin Date] = MAX([Begin Date]),
  [End Date] = MAX([End Date])
FROM TableA a
GROUP BY
  ID
HAVING COUNT([End Date]) = 0;
```

If you want to see all rows for that ID then use a window function

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      CountEnd = COUNT([End Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
    FROM TableA a
) a
WHERE CountEnd = 0
ORDER BY
  ID,
  [Begin Date] DESC;
```

---

**For your new requirement:** Just use standard row-numbering techniques

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Begin Date] DESC)
    FROM TableA a
) a
WHERE rn = 1
  AND [End Date] IS NULL
ORDER BY
  ID,
  [Begin Date] DESC;
```

Comment: I made an edit to the original question, your code actually works to my original but I realized some other changes that need to be made

Comment: You can just use row-numbering for that. See edits. In future please do NOT modify the question after it's been answered. instead create a new question for that.